# Como zerar o auto-increment do MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Galera como faço pra zerar o auto incremento do PHPMyadmin?
ja tentei

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Mas não funcionou

Comment: Da algum erro? o que acontece?

Comment: Não acontece nada, so não reseta continua adicionando de onde parou

Answer (score 6):

Lembre-se de excluir todos os registros da tabela antes de usar o comanda que você tentou.

```
ALTER TABLE tabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Você pode usar o painel do `PHPMyAdmin`, selecionar a tabela e depois o menu `Operações`, basta alterar nas configurações `Opções da tabela > AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Se tiver dados no banco ele não reseta o auto increment?

Comment: Eu preciso disso pra poder fazer o php salvar dados novos nos id's que ja foram excluidos

Comment: Se tiver registros ele não vai zerar, o que você pode fazer é alterar para o próximo ID, ele nunca vai voltar para o ID anterior ao último registro

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema (e você **NÃO** está sozinho) é um simples TOC devido a registros deletados. A recomendação sempre é não se preocupar com os vazios que o MySQL acaba deixanndo, pois a coluna id não foi feita para ser humanamente legível.

Na linha temporal de um sistema, quando uma chave primária é deletada, você pode fazer com que acessos referenciais sejam quebrados automaticamente (O sistema lhe diz que o registro 237 não existe mais). Se você preencher esse espaço com um registro diferente, pode acabar tendo mais transtornos do que soluções.

O comando que você está executando faz exatamente o seguinte

```
SELECT (MAX(id)+1) INTO @var FROM table;
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = @var;
```

Ou seja, se sua base de dados tem o registro 1 e depois o 15, o comando que busca o max(id) + 1 vai retornar 16, definindo seu auto incremento para 16.

Answer (score -1):

Se você tiver um campo id com a ordem assim:

1

2

4

usar isso não irá resolver, pois a desordem está no meio. Você pode reordenar tudo com:

```
ALTER TABLE `bd`.`table` DROP `id`

ALTER TABLE `bd`.`table` ADD `id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Isso irá remover o campo id e fazer um novo, assim a ordem irá voltar para:

1

2

3